# Error during rate request at Dhl/Express/Webservice/Soap/RateServiceAdapter.php:77

Tags: magento2.3, soap, webapi, dhl, msi

I have upgraded magento 2.2.4 to 2.3.2. After upgrade version we have enabled MSI modules. After Enabling MSI modules we are getting below error when we try to create shipment. We are not able to create shipment.

> Exception:
>
> main.ERROR: Error during rate request. {"exception":"[object]
>   (Dhl\Express\Exception\SoapException(code: 0): Could not access
>   SOAP webservice. at
>   html/app/code/Dhl/Express/Webservice/Soap/RateServiceAdapter.php:77)"}

```
System Log:
main.ERROR: Could not access SOAP webservice.
```

Comment: Any solution? Getting same error.

Comment: I am also getting the same error. Any update on this?